# What do you call servo connectors?

Tags: servo

What do you call the outlets/plugs/connectors that you plug servos into on a board? These things circled in the photo...

[image]

I'm trying to purchase these and have no idea how to find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are known as **"HEADERS & RECEPTACLES"** TE calls it as a **AMPMODU MTE** series.
can be found below at Digikey

3- Pin :-

Header:- [5-147278-2](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/5-147278-2/A100890TR-ND/2259076)

Plug:-[5-103960-2](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/5-103960-2/5-103960-2-ND/2259330)

4- Pin :-

Header:- [5-147278-3](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/5-147278-3/A100868TR-ND/2258826)

Plug:- [5-103970-3](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/5-103970-3/A115229-ND/2286273)

If you need the header with more pin, just play with the last digit of the above header part numbers for example if you need 5 Pin header connector change the last digit of 4- Pin of header part number from 5-147278-**3** to 5-147278-**4**

Comment: Thank you, I found this better header however, http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/0705530002/WM4901-ND/114955

Comment: Also price of the headers on this page are much more reasonable: http://www.hansenhobbies.com/products/connectors/pt1inlpconnectors/pt1in_lp_1x3/

Comment: Thats great :-)